# Read large file header (~9GB) inside tarfile without full extraction

Tags: python, large-files, bzip2, tarfile

I have ~1GB *.tbz files. Inside each of those files there is a single ~9GB file. I just need to read the header of this file, the first 1024 bytes.

I want this to do this as fast as possible as I have hundreds of this 1GB files I want to process. It takes about 1m30s to extract.

I tried using full extraction:

```
tar = tarfile.open(fn, mode='r|bz2')
for item in tar:
    tar.extract(item)
```

and `tarfile.getmembers()` but with no speed imprevement:

```
tar = tarfile.open(fn, mode='r|bz2')
for member in tar.getmembers():
    f = tar.extractfile(member)
    headerbytes = f.read(1024)
    headerdict = parseHeader(headerbytes)
```

The `getmembers()` method is what's taking all the time there.

Is there any way I can to this?

Comment: Can you show a sample header that you need to parse?

Comment: Can you use [BZ2File](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2File) to `read` out a chunk? You can skip the `tar` part completely, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Would you like to post a full answer? 

    f = bz2.BZ2File(fn); 
    f.seek(512); 
    headerbytes = f.read(1024); 
    headerdict = parseHeader(headerbytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the standard library `bz2` interface. `.tbz` is the file extension for `tar` files that are compressed with the `-j` option to specify a `bzip2` format.

As [@bbayles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353839/bbayles) pointed out in the comments, you can open your file as a [`bz2.BZ2File`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2File) and use `seek` and `read`:

> read([size])
>
> Read at most size uncompressed bytes, returned as a
>   string. If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is
>   reached.
>
> seek(offset[, whence])
>
> Move to new file position. Argument offset is a
>   byte count.

```
f = bz2.BZ2File(path)
f.seek(512) 
headerbytes = f.read(1024)
```

You can then parse that with your functions.

```
headerdict = parseHeader(headerbytes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the full answer Sebastian! @bbayles gave the main lead first. I actually solved it with his comment before you posted your full answer. I would like to give him some credit too. Do you know a way to add him to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that every tar archive will contain only a single bz2 file, you can simply skip the first 512 bytes when first reading the tar file (NOT the bz2 file contained in it, of course), because the tar file format has a padded (fixed size) header, after which your "real" content is stored.

A simple

```
f.seek(512)
```

instead of looping over getmembers() should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpfull but not a complete answer.